# How to check a process is killed and started again in linux command

Tags: java, linux, command-line, process

I have command where it performs a sort of front end restart. This process kills the currently running java instance (process) and once the restart completes, it automatically restarts the java instance (as a result of front end restart). 
Is there a way to monitor(observe) this process (killing process and re-spawn) process using one command.

Comment: ps -ef , i think just search in Goolge first is ok for you.

Comment: I did, I was expecting a real time monitoring where it gives process killed instance and process spawn instance using one command :)